# How to add a <!-- message --> to an email for parsing?

Tags: php, email, parsing

I am writing a code that will take a user reply to an automated message and parse out any previous discussion. then take the body of the new email and insert it into a database.

I thought I can add `<!-- This is the message break -->` to the very top of my message and from there I can remove anything under this phrase when reading the email. using something like this
 `$newReply = strstr($message, '<!-- This is the message break -->',true);`

But for some reason the email server seems to be removing the page break that I added `(ie. <!-- This is the message break -->)` I can't find it in the email.

Here is the html code that I am using to send it as an email using php `mail()` function.

```
<!-- This is the message break -->
<html>
<body>

<table rules="all" style="padding: 10px; line-height: 1.42857143; vertical-align: Middle; border: 5px solid #1A1A1C; width: 780px; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="text-align: center; background-color: #1A1A1C; color: #fff;  padding: 5px;">Need to respond? Just hit reply, a responses will be appended to ticket details automatically</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="100" style="color: #333333; font-weight: bold;  border-top: 1px solid #DBDBDB; border-right: 1px solid #DBDBDB; border-bottom: 1px solid #DBDBDB; border-left: 5px solid #1A1A1C; background-color: #F0F0F0;">Subject</td>
<td style="color: #333333;   border-top: 1px solid #DBDBDB; border-right: 5px solid #1A1A1C; border-bottom: 1px solid #DBDBDB; border-left: 1px solid #DBDBDB;  background-color: #F0F0F0;">'.strip_tags($ticketInfo['title']).'</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="100" style="color: #333333; font-weight: bold;  border-top: 1px solid #DBDBDB; border-right: 1px solid #DBDBDB; border-bottom: 1px solid #DBDBDB; border-left: 5px solid #1A1A1C;">Ticket #</td>
<td style="color: #333333;   border-top: 1px solid #DBDBDB; border-right: 5px solid #1A1A1C; border-bottom: 1px solid #DBDBDB; border-left: 1px solid #DBDBDB; ">'.$ticketInfo['issue_id'].'</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="100" style="color: #333333; font-weight: bold;  border-top: 1px solid #DBDBDB; border-right: 1px solid #DBDBDB; border-bottom: 1px solid #DBDBDB; border-left: 5px solid #1A1A1C; background-color: #F0F0F0;">Notification</td>
<td style="color: #333333;   border-top: 1px solid #DBDBDB; border-right: 5px solid #1A1A1C; border-bottom: 1px solid #DBDBDB; border-left: 1px solid #DBDBDB;  background-color: #F0F0F0;">'.$ticketInfo['notificationType'].'</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="100" style="color: #333333; font-weight: bold;  border-top: 1px solid #DBDBDB; border-right: 1px solid #DBDBDB; border-bottom: 1px solid #DBDBDB; border-left: 5px solid #1A1A1C;">Status</td>
<td style="color: #333333;   border-top: 1px solid #DBDBDB; border-right: 5px solid #1A1A1C; border-bottom: 1px solid #DBDBDB; border-left: 1px solid #DBDBDB; ">'.$ticketInfo['ticketStatus'].'</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="100" style="color: #333333; font-weight: bold;  border-top: 1px solid #DBDBDB; border-right: 1px solid #DBDBDB; border-bottom: 1px solid #DBDBDB; border-left: 5px solid #1A1A1C; background-color: #F0F0F0;">Priority</td>
<td style="color: #333333;   border-top: 1px solid #DBDBDB; border-right: 5px solid #1A1A1C; border-bottom: 1px solid #DBDBDB; border-left: 1px solid #DBDBDB;  background-color: #F0F0F0;">'.$ticketInfo['priority']. ' - ' . $ticketInfo['ticket_type'] .'</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="100" style="color: #333333; font-weight: bold;  border-top: 1px solid #DBDBDB; border-right: 1px solid #DBDBDB; border-bottom: 1px solid #DBDBDB; border-left: 5px solid #1A1A1C;">Ticket Assigned To</td>
<td style="color: #333333;   border-top: 1px solid #DBDBDB; border-right: 5px solid #1A1A1C; border-bottom: 1px solid #DBDBDB; border-left: 1px solid #DBDBDB; ">'.$ticketInfo['assigned_to'].'</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="100" style="color: #333333; font-weight: bold;  border-top: 1px solid #DBDBDB; border-right: 1px solid #DBDBDB; border-bottom: 1px solid #DBDBDB; border-left: 5px solid #1A1A1C; background-color: #F0F0F0;">Client Name</td>
<td style="color: #333333;   border-top: 1px solid #DBDBDB; border-right: 5px solid #1A1A1C; border-bottom: 1px solid #DBDBDB; border-left: 1px solid #DBDBDB;  background-color: #F0F0F0;">'.$ticketInfo['client_name'].'</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2">
'.$notes.'

<br /><br /><strong><em>To comment on this ticket, you can either replay directly to this email, or click the link below to view previous comments</em></strong><br />
<a href="'.$url .'"><em>Click Here To View This Ticket</em><a/><br /><br />
</td>
</tr>   

</table>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Comments might be removed by parsers – after all, they are _comments_ and therefor by definition are not meant to transport any sort of meaning. You’re probably better of by wrapping an actual HTML element, such as a `<div class="previous-message">` … `</div>` around the original part of the message.

Comment: @CBroe thank you.. I have tried that now and it seems to be parsing out the `class="previous-message"`  it seems to be leaving <div>

Comment: @CBroe You should add it as an answer since it help to solve the OP's problem.

Comment: Well, with email clients you can never be sure what they might parse out … “inlining” CSS is quite common practice, especially for web-based email viewers, so it is quite possible that classes are removed. You could try adding a text instead (preferably something that makes sense in case it would be read out, f.e. by a screen reader), and wrap that into an element that hides it via `style="display:none"` – even if that particular style should be removed, at least the text itself should survive.